# Force UTF-8 output using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xd7' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

from this code :

```
test_string = """
Antelope Canyon, Arizona [1600×1068] </a>&#32; <span class="domain">(<a
"""

print(test_string)
```

output of sys.getdefaultencoding :

```
In [6]: sys.getdefaultencoding()
Out[10]: 'utf-8'
```

I'm using a Chromebook with crouton - if that makes a difference (I've a feeling that it might).

I'm not sure if there's some way of 'forcing' the output of strings like this or just ignoring any chars that are problematic.

> terminal or console o redirect cannot handle UTF-8; what environment are you trying to print in.

I'm trying to run this using iPython within Spacemacs

```
In [22]: sys.stdout.encoding
Out[27]: 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

> In the shell, what does the command locale output?

In the shell I'm running this within (iPython within Spacemacs) the command is undefined, on the default shell brought up with `ctrl alt t` the output is

```
$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Ah, the `×` is the U+00D7 character.

Comment: @MartijnPieters cheers - I'm thinking that it might be some Chromebook related issue as everything looks funky here http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/unicode-sample-3-2.html , not sure how to confirm though as It's all i currently have access to

Comment: Your terminal or console o redirect cannot handle UTF-8; what environment are you trying to print *in*.

Comment: What matters here is `sys.stdout.encoding`, which is set from the parent process (usually the shell).

Comment: On my Linux, using Python 3.5, your code works fine.

Comment: @KevinGuan: that's because your shell has a decent locale configured.

Comment: In the shell, what does the command `locale` output?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, however I configured the locale use `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @KevinGuan: exactly. But the OP is using a Chromebook..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have updated the post with response to those questions - thanks

Comment: If you are using an Emacs environment, use `(setenv "LC_CTYPE" "UTF-8")` to set a locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a POSIX host, Python determines the output encoding from the *locale*, a set of environment variables that communicate how the environment is configured for various language settings. See the [`locale.getdefaultlocale()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale), or more specifically, the [`locale.getpreferredencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) function.

The output of that function is used to set `sys.stdout.encoding`, which is then used to encode any Unicode text printed.

Your locale is set to `POSIX`, which means that the default encoding is ASCII. You'll need to configure that locale to use an encoding that supports all of Unicode. How to do this for Chromebooks, I don't know. On my Mac, the locale is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, mostly, so all of the Unicode standard is supported by my terminal. You could force the issue by setting `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`.

You can override Python's choices by setting the [`PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING).

Note that on more recent Python 3 releases, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` use the [`backslashescape` error handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers), which replaces any character your console can't handle with the standard `\xhh`, `\uhhhh` and `\Uhhhhhhhh` escape sequences; so instead of an exception you'd see:

```
Antelope Canyon, Arizona [1600\xd71068] </a>&#32; <span class="domain">(<a
```

Comment: I should be able to get it working from here, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ah, after search and search, I found [this](http://www.helptouser.com/unixlinux/152224-chromebook-crouton-debian-xfce4-cannot-change-locale.html). As it says maybe you could try:

1. Edit (create it first) `/etc/locale.gen` file.
2. Write the following text in it:

   ```
   en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
   LC_ALL="en_GB.UTF-8"
   ```
3. Maybe try reboot the Chromebook.

And then check the `locale` command's output.